# CloudFormation: duplicate / existing Route53 record set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a CloudFormation template for the following situation:

- template parameterized by environment: DEV, QA, PROD
- Route 53 RecordSet for routing downstream service URLs to VPCe's
- The URLs are set in stone (correspond to shared hosted zone mappings)
- DEV and QA share the same downstream URL
- CloudFormation fails to create the QA RecordSet since it exists - been already created for DEV

Any suggestions for how to cleanly get around this?

Done some investigation, but can't find how to make this operation an UPSERT instead of a CREATE in the CloudFormation files. 
One option I've seen is: creating a custom resource with a lambda that deploys the RecordSet resources as an UPSERT operation, but this seems really elaborate for what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Is this something that doesn't need to be run at all for the QA stack? If so, try using a condition that is based on that.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Hm, maybe as a temporary fix, but it's possible for DEV and QA to use different URLs, so I should allow for that.
Maybe I could use a condition that checks if DEV / QA have equal URLs, and skip the QA RecordSet. Not sure if there's a cleaner solution...

Comment: I think comparing the two is a fine solution.